# Subset dataframe with equal difference for one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, diff

I am trying to iterate the rows in a dataframe (data) to check if one of the columns (data$ID) has similar difference (e.g., 3) between consecutive elements. If yes, keep the row, otherwise remove the row. The tricky part is I need to re-compare consecutive elements after certain row is removed.

```
data <- data.frame(ID=c(3.1, 6, 6.9, 9, 10.5, 12, 14.2, 15),
                   score = c(70, 80, 90, 65, 43, 78, 44, 92))
data
    ID    score
1   3.1     70
2   6     80
3   6.9     90
4   9     65
5   10.5    43
6   12    78
7   14.2    44
8   15    92

for (i in (length(data$ID)-1)) {
    first <- data$ID[i]
    second <- data$ID[i+1]
    if ((second-first) == 3){
       data <- data[-(i+1),]
    }    
 }
```

The expected output data should be

```
    ID    score
1   3.1     70
2   6     80
3   9     65
4   12    78
5   15    92
```

The initial row 3, 5, 7 are excluded due to the different diff. But my code failed.

I also try to use diff function,

```
DF <- diff(data)
```

But it doesn't take care the fact that after one row is removed, the difference will change. Should I use diff function in a loop, but the dataframe is dynamic changed.

Comment: Why is the first row in your expected output?

Comment: In your question you refer to similar distance as `diff == 3`; but in your code you check for `diff == 2`? Why is row 7 not included and row 8 removed. The difference to row 6 is > 2, so row 7 should be kept, shouldn't it? Obviously this will depend on whether you calculate difference top to bottom, or bottom to top. Which one is it supposed to be?

Comment: The first row is a benchmark for getting started calculating difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a recursive function (a function that calls itself)

```
data <- data.frame(ID=c(3.1, 6, 6.9, 9, 10.5, 12, 14.2, 15),
                   score = c(70, 80, 90, 65, 43, 78, 44, 92))

# use recursive function to trim the remainder of the list
trim_ids <- function (ids) {
  # if only one element, return it
  if (length(ids) <= 1) {
    return(ids) 
  }
   # if the gap between element 2 and element 1 is small enough 
  if ((ids[2] - ids[1]) < 2.9 ) {
    # trim after dropping the second element
    return(trim_ids(ids[-2])) 
  } else {
    # keep the first element and trim from the second element
    return(c(ids[1], trim_ids(ids[2:length(ids)] )))
  }
}

# find the ids to keep
keep_ids <- trim_ids(data$ID)

# select the matching rows
data[data$ID %in% keep_ids,]

#      ID score
# 1  3.1    70
# 2  6.0    80
# 4  9.0    65
# 6 12.0    78
# 8 15.0    92
```

Comment: This solution is more general following the logic, and also works for small or integer numbers, such as 0.3 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

An option could be achieved using `cumsum` and `diff` as:

```
#data
data <- data.frame(ID=c(3.1, 6, 6.9, 9, 10.5, 12, 14.2, 15),
                   score = c(70, 80, 90, 65, 43, 78, 44, 92))


data[c(0, cumsum(diff(round(data$ID))) %% 3 ) == 0,]

# ID score
# 1  3.1    70
# 2  6.0    80
# 4  9.0    65
# 6 12.0    78
# 8 15.0    92
```

Comment: Any idea if diff is a small number, such as 0.3?

Answer (score 0):

If you define you want to keep all rows of which the ID, when rounded to 0 digits, belongs to a product of 3, you could try:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(3.1, 6, 6.9, 9, 10.5, 12, 14.2, 15),
               score = c(70, 80, 90, 65, 43, 78, 44, 92))


df1[round(df1$ID) %% 3 == 0,]

ID score
1  3.1    70
2  6.0    80
4  9.0    65
6 12.0    78
8 15.0    92
```

Comment: That will work for this example but most probably would fail otherwise.